# Transition between hybrid bike and endurance road bike

Tags: road-bike, hybrid-bike

What are the different skills I need to develop when transitioning between a hybrid bike and an endurance road bike?

Comment: A stronger butt.

Comment: That is a good point - you may need to go through more saddle trials on a road bike than on a hybrid.

Comment: Aside from all the answers here, your title has one thing no one mentioned. **Endurance** You need to develop the ability to pedal for hours on end, eating and drinking while riding.

Comment: You don't need to use an endurance road bike for endurance racing/riding. =)

Comment: If your road bike has brake lever with integrated shifters, this will take some getting used to.

Answer (score 5):

You probably just have to get used to the geometry of the endurance road bike (since most hybrids are closer to MTB hardtail geometry), which can be helped with bike fit, so the drop bar and saddle are positioned in a way where you can use all the hand positions of the bike (hoods, drops, middle of the bar, sides, etc.) efficiently and comfortably for the type of riding you're doing.

Also, you should be more aware of road hazards, since most endurance road bikes have weaker wheels than a hybrid, to save weight - bunny hopping can be useful for this.

Also, if you're using clipless pedals (or clipped pedals) on the road bike and not on the hybrid, make sure to practice clipping in and out before you hit the road (unless you like your face hitting the ground...)

Comment: Good work @Batman. Such things become unconscious after a while!

Answer (score 5):

Having made this transition myself, you may need to get used to the following things.

- **Gear shifters**. The action will be unfamiliar, so you may need to think before a change, so try to change in advance of stops at junctions and avoid shifting whilst out of the saddle.
- **Body position**, especially in the drops. It can help to physically train so that your body can deal with this easily. For example, try [the plank](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/fitness-strengthen-your-core-with-the-plank-26223/). As mentioned, bike fit can also help.
- **Handling**. An endurance bike often has a longer trail, meaning it it stable and holds its course well, but may be less manoeuvrable, especially at low speeds. So take care in traffic.
- **Maintenance**. Make sure you understand how to adjust the brakes, etc and have appropriate spare parts which may be different from the hybrid.

Comment: You'd have to think about shifting on a hybrid as well, provided you don't own a Rohloff hybrid (but, getting used to brifters/bar ends/downtube shifters does take a bit relative to trigger/grip shift). Maintenance is a good point. As for the drops, you also need to make sure the drops are even usable (if they're too deep, you're never going to use them).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly fitted to the bike, and just ride it. It does not have to be an elaborate formal fitting but a competent bike shop (or very knowledgable biking friend) should look at your posture on the bike and adjust accordingly.

The best way to get used to a bike is to go out and ride it.